# RMI Calls to secured EJB3 method fails

Tags: security, ejb-3.0

I have following configurations in my ejb-jar.xml;

```
 <assembly-descriptor>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>userRole</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <method-permission>
        <role-name>userRole</role-name>
        <method>
            <ejb-name>MyBean</ejb-name>
            <method-name>*</method-name>
        </method>
    </method-permission>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

And I have configured following in my jboss.xml as security domain (default domain with additional user I have added as follows;

```
....
<security-domain>java:/jaas/JBossWS</security-domain>
...

User Properties Files Have Following;
SSOUSER=123456

User Roles Files have Following;
SSOUSER=userRole
```

I have written folliwing code in my client to connect to JNP;

```
Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099"); // remote machine IP
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "SSOUSER"); // User Context
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "123456");
```

And getting following error on jBoss console while trying to access the bean method (lookup works OK, as soon as I try to call method I get following);

```
16:43:42,987 ERROR [RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor] Insufficient permissions, principal=null, requiredRoles=[userRole], principalRoles=[]
```

Is there anything missing in my configurations?

Thanks

--

Sjunejo

Answer (score 1):

After searching for quite long I found following which helped;

https://community.jboss.org/message/251308

Th change I have made are as follows;

```
Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
environment.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099"); // remote machine IP
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "SSOUSER"); // User Context
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "123456");
```

Everything remain unchanged, I was using the incorrect INTIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY i.e 'org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory', when I switched to '**org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory**', I got the PRINCIPAL in my EJB from SessionContext